# How do I echo multidimensional array values by table rows instead of columns in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to display a multidimensional array from my database into an Html table with PHP, row by row instead of column by column.
I have the following array;

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
       [0] => Paracetamol 
       [1] => Caffeine
       [2] => Pase 
   ) 
   [1] => Array ( 
       [0] => 12
       [1] => 10
       [2] => 1
   ) 
   [2] => Array (
       [0] => Packets
       [1] => Cartons
       [2] => Containers
   )
)
```

I tried using foreach and here is the output I got;
https://jsfiddle.net/fraqy912/1/
But, this is the output that I'm actually trying to achieve;
https://jsfiddle.net/5akgjtvf/3/

Comment: Please share your current code so we can help debug it.

Comment: Hello @Nick, I used the answer provided below by Anik-anwar and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $array = Array (
                Array ( 
                   'Paracetamol',
                   'Caffeine',
                   'Pase'
                ),
                Array ( 
                   12,
                   10,
                   1
                ),
                Array ( 
                   'Packets',
                   'Cartons',
                   'Containers'
                )
            );

   function combine($array) {
        array_unshift($array, null);
        return call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
    }

    $array = combine($array);
?>
<table border="1">
        <tr>
        <th>Product_name</th>
        <th>Product_quantity</th>
        <th>Product_size</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($array as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?=$row[0]?></td>
      <td><?=$row[2]?></td>
      <td><?=$row[1]?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try transposing the array

```
function transpose($array) {
    array_unshift($array, null);
    return call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
}
```

Or

```
function transpose($array) {
    return array_map(null, ...$array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is something which will give you idea to do your task.

```
<?php
$meds = Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
       [0] => Paracetamol 
       [1] => Caffeine
       [2] => Pase 
   ) 
   [1] => Array ( 
       [0] => 12
       [1] => 10
       [2] => 1
   ) 
   [2] => Array (
       [0] => Packets
       [1] => Cartons
       [2] => Containers
   )
);

echo "<table>";    
    foreach($meds as $itemz) {      
        echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($itemz as $item) {
                echo "<td>".$item."</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<br >";
    }       
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the answer. I tried it but unfortunately, it still displayed the same.

Comment: Br tags are invalid html inside tables.

Answer (score 0):

actually there are many ways, I will give one of them

```
<?php 
    $myArray = Array (
                Array ( 
                   'Paracetamol',
                   'Caffeine',
                   'Pase'
                ),
                Array ( 
                   12,
                   10,
                   1
                ),
                Array ( 
                   'Packets',
                   'Cartons',
                   'Containers'
                )
            );

    $tableData          = '';
    foreach ($myArray as $datas){
        $tableData      .= '<tr>';

        foreach ($datas as $data){
            $tableData      .= '<td>';
            $tableData      .= $data;
            $tableData      .= '</td>';
        }

        $tableData      .= '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
    <table border="1">
        <?php
        echo $tableData;
        ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the answer. I tried it but unfortunately, it still displayed the same.